# Do I need to count 3 functions (create, update and delete) in Function Point Analysis?

Tags: function-points

I have an ILF that receive External Inputs (EI).

Do I need to count 3 function points? (create, update, delete)
Or I need to count just one? (maintain)

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. I found this: http://www.devdaily.com/fpa/fpa-borland/ei-delete-processes.shtml